# Rails - Are there better alternatives to collect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Edited my question to be more specific about what I'm asking..

I have nested associations in my data which i eager load and then want to use collect to do some sub processing. So say I have posts that have comments that has an owner attribute. So I do

```
Post.includes(:comments).collect(&:owner)
```

..and then do some stuff with the owners. Is there a better way to grab the owners?

Comment: `all` returns every record and then you are filtering using `collect` - try using activerecord `where` - i.e. `Model.where(:some_attr => true)`

Comment: @house9 thanks I've edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [`pluck`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck)?

> ```
> Client.where(:active => true).pluck(:id)
> # SELECT id FROM clients WHERE active = 1
>
> Client.uniq.pluck(:role)
> # SELECT DISTINCT role FROM clients
> ```

Comment: Note that pluck is not available on all Rails versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`Activerecord::Base#select`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields):

```
Model.today.select([:attr1, :attr2, :attr3]) # chainable method
# will generate this query
# SELECT attr1, attr2, attr3 FROM models
```

Comment: Note that this will return instances of `MyModel` that only have attributes adn values for the selected columns. If `MyModel` has an `id`, `name`, and `date`, and you do `MyModel.select(:name)` all your instances returned will look like `#<MyModel name='Fred'>, etc`. And if you tried to access another attribute on it, it will come back as nil.

Comment: I should add that this means your DB query is faster as it's selecting less, but if you wanted a Ruby array with all the names (for example) you'd still have to use `collect` to grab them.

Comment: Actually, I thought that was the purpose of the question. Getting all columns from a fat table when you only need names is not as fast as it could.

Comment: I just wanted the asker to have more information on what this will return. Yes you definitely helped make the query better, but to someone who has not seen the `select` method before it may look like calling it will return you an array of those attributes, and not an array of model instances.

Answer (score 0):

Rails will work out what you want if you add a has_many_through association.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commenters, through: :comments, source: :owner
  ...
end

male_gardeners = Post.find_by(slug: 'in_the_garden').commenters.where(gender: 'M')
```